# How to change a string to an int using Convert.ToSingle() in C#

Tags: c#, casting

I am making an age calculator, and am asking for the person birth month and year. They are to enter the month as a number, e.g. may would be 5. After that I am doing a    `System.Convert.ToSingle()` on the string for their birth month. But It says I need a cast. I don't know how to format a cast on this and have researched it for about an hour. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
static void Age()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What month were you born in?");
        string ageMonth = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What year were you born in?");
        string ageYear = Console.ReadLine();

        DateTime currentMonth = DateTime.Now;

        int numberMonth;
        numberMonth = Convert.ToSingle(ageMonth);
    }
```

Comment: `numberMonth`  is an `int`. Why do you want to use here `Convert.ToSingle` method?

Comment: Remember to catch exceptions if people type in something that isn't a number

Comment: You mean to use Convert.ToInt(ageMonth), but you might want to look into int.TryParse() as well

Comment: ToSingle() converts a specified value to a single-precision floating-point number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use int.Parse

```
int.Parse(ageMonth)
```

Answer (score 3):

`int numberMonth = int.Parse(ageMonth);`

Note that this will throw an exception if ageMonth doesn't contain a valid integer.

Answer (score 2):

You should probaly use

`int.TryParse(ageMonth, out numberMonth)`

Handle the boolean result to make sure that they actually input an int because other options would through an exception if the user did not input an `int`(returns true if it was converted and then `numberMonth` has the int that was parsed, false if the string could not be parsed). Never trust users to input the right type of information and you should protect your code.

Comment: I had wondered about if they had not put in an integer, thanks for the `out numberMonth`